# Sort multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array in the following form

```
array:2 [▼
  "dashboardData" => array:1 [▶]
  "widgetData" => array:5 [▼
    0 => {#214 ▼
      +"_id": "575fcf6d298fbfd833000041"
      +"created": "2016-06-14T09:33:33.492Z"
      +"dashboardid": "575fcebc298fbfd833000036"
      +"datasource": {#215 ▶}
    }
    1 => {#249 ▶}
    2 => {#285 ▶}
    3 => {#297 ▶}
    4 => {#333 ▶}
  ]
]
```

I have deleted a lot of data but the above just be enough to demonstrate what I am after.  Essentially, the widgetData part of my array has a random order for its elements.

As you can see above though, each element in this part of my array has a created value.  Is it possible to order just this part of my array (widgetData) based on the created date?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of end result do you need? Are you trying to extract the created date or sort the array with it?

Comment: I am looking for the eact same result, just with the first created date in position 0 in the array.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because your dates are using standard UTC date strings, you can sort your array by iterating the components and assigning the values to the original array (assuming it's variable), i.e:

```
let arrayCopy = array
for index in 0..<arrayCopy.count {
    if let widgetData: [[String: AnyObject]] = array[index]["widgetData"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        let sortedWidgetData = widgetData.sort({ (dictionary1, dictionary2) -> Bool in
            return (dictionary1["created"] as! String) < (dictionary2["created"] as! String)
        })
        array[index]["widgetData"] = sortedWidgetData
    }
}
```

You could also just do this at runtime on your datasource as and when it's needed.

Comment: Hi, that is not written in PHP is it?  Doesnt look familiar to me.]